# Call a Web App script from within a spreadsheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I call an external Google Web App script from within my script in a Google spreadsheet container? I have a number of spreadsheets that are created dynamically and would like them all to call a single Web App for uniformity and ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this blog post: [Trigger updates between master – slave spreadsheets](http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/18/trigger-updates-between-master-slave-spreadsheets/)
Basically what you want to accomplish in the same, in the specific scenario the master spreadsheet is actually a web app (web service) for all the slave spreadsheet documents.

Comment: Site has gone. Domain redirects to some malware which tries to change your Chrome default search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a textbook use of Google Apps Script Libraries! Start by reading [Introducing Versions and Libraries in Apps Script](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2012/05/introducing-versions-and-libraries-in.html).

Your master script, plus any utilities you want to access, needs to be set up as a library, for example let's say it's called `MyLib`. Your dynamically created (client) spreadsheets then access functions that are in `MyLib` by treating it as a javascript object. For example, a function `calcValues()` would be referenced like this:

```
...
var result = MyLib.calcValues(dataRange);
...
```

You didn't ask this, but just in case you're thinking of using custom functions (as described in [Custom Functions in Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions)) that are implemented in your library / master script, you will need to provide wrapper functions in your client spreadsheets. Here's that same example as a wrapper:

```
function calcValues (dataRange) {
  return MyLib.calcValues(dataRange);
}
```