# Google Apps Script custom functions for Google Sheets outside of Code.gs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm building an add-on. I've noticed I can have multiple html files. Can I also have multiple code files, that is, more than just Code.gs?

If so, how to I cause them to be loaded? If not, how does Sheets know whether a function defined in Code.gs can be used in a formula or not?

**LATER**

So it has been suggested, seeing that the script editor allows you to create extra gs files, that simply having the custom function in another script file within the add-on is sufficient. However, I'm not having a lot of success with that.

So apart from my Code.gs, I have Medical.gs with the following in it:

```
/**
 * Gargling function for digital sore throat
 *
 * @param {object} input The thing to gargle
 * @return the gargled parameter
 * @customfunction
 */
function GARGLE(input) {
  console.log("GARGLE");
  return "GARGLE";
}
```

Even with the JSDoc header, the custom function is invisible when, from the Run menu in the Script Editor, I select the "Test as add-on" and run the prepared test spreadsheet. In the spreadsheet I can do `=GARGLE()` as much as I like, but I still get the standard `#NAME?` error.

**LATER STILL**

So I put a similar custom function into a fresh standalone script project's Code.gs. When tested as an add-on the target spreadsheet can't even see *this* one. Going slightly nuts here.

Comment: You can have any number of script files in your Spreadsheet file Project.  You just go to code editor, File -> New -> Script file.  Each function is defined by a name.  You can't have more than one function with the same name.  Then you can execute a function by name(...) where the ... may be parameters.  You could execute the same function as a custom funtion in a spreadsheet cell by entering =name(...).  Its the same for a web app, the Project knows the names off all the function in the multiple script pages.

Comment: All Apps Script files share the same namespace currently.

Comment: your custom function works fine for me

Comment: @beano (the kids loved that comic back in the day) Yeah the function works fine in certain contexts but not in others. If I have an AddOn with a single Code.gs file and that function in it and then test it as an addon from the script editor, it doesn't get seen by Google Sheets. Maybe I should reboot my laptop ... the usual response when things go anomalous.

Comment: @TheWizEd I was rather wanting to develop a standalone rather than a bound.

Comment: Doesn't matter, your project can have any number of script pages.  Did you republish your web app?

Comment: Also take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259755/call-a-web-app-script-from-within-a-spreadsheet-script

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue concerning custom functions not working with the menu item

test-as-add-on

https://issuetracker.google.com/36763437

Currently you must use a script bound to your Sheet in order to test your functions.